# Vue js ReferenceError: navigator is not defined

Tags: vue.js

I'm getting the error below upon refreshing the page:

```
ReferenceError: navigator is not defined
    at VueComponent.isMobile (src/views/user/Profile.vue:71:0)
    at fn (src/views/user/PublicProfile.vue?504b:30:0)
    at normalized (/Users/mark/Desktop/Sirius/SRS-556/sirius/node_modules/vue/dist/vue.runtime.common.dev.js:2584:37)
    at Proxy.renderSlot (/Users/mark/Desktop/Sirius/SRS-556/sirius/node_modules/vue/dist/vue.runtime.common.dev.js:2680:13)
    at Proxy.render (src/components/layouts/TwoColumn.vue?3126:22:0)
    at VueComponent.Vue._render (/Users/mark/Desktop/Sirius/SRS-556/sirius/node_modules/vue/dist/vue.runtime.common.dev.js:3538:22)
    at resolve (/Users/mark/Desktop/Sirius/SRS-556/sirius/node_modules/vue-server-renderer/build.dev.js:8415:27)
    at waitForServerPrefetch (/Users/mark/Desktop/Sirius/SRS-556/sirius/node_modules/vue-server-renderer/build.dev.js:8287:3)
    at renderComponentInner (/Users/mark/Desktop/Sirius/SRS-556/sirius/node_modules/vue-server-renderer/build.dev.js:8426:3)
    at renderComponent (/Users/mark/Desktop/Sirius/SRS-556/sirius/node_modules/vue-server-renderer/build.dev.js:8383:5)
    at RenderContext.renderNode (/Users/mark/Desktop/Sirius/SRS-556/sirius/node_modules/vue-server-renderer/build.dev.js:8294:5)
    at RenderContext.next (/Users/mark/Desktop/Sirius/SRS-556/sirius/node_modules/vue-server-renderer/build.dev.js:2598:23)
    at cachedWrite (/Users/mark/Desktop/Sirius/SRS-556/sirius/node_modules/vue-server-renderer/build.dev.js:2451:9)
    at renderElement (/Users/mark/Desktop/Sirius/SRS-556/sirius/node_modules/vue-server-renderer/build.dev.js:8544:5)
    at renderNode (/Users/mark/Desktop/Sirius/SRS-556/sirius/node_modules/vue-server-renderer/build.dev.js:8296:5)
    at resolve (/Users/mark/Desktop/Sirius/SRS-556/sirius/node_modules/vue-server-renderer/build.dev.js:8421:5)
    at runMicrotasks ()
    at processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:96:5)
```

For example, suppose I'm in `127.0.0.1` and then I navigate to `127.0.0.1/test/`. No error occurs for me but if I am already at the `/test/` and then refreshes the page then the above error occurs.

The code in question is below:

```
<template #default>
    <u-modal v-model="reportUser" :min-width="isMobile() == true ? '150px' : '700px'" :max-width="isMobile() == true ? '300px' : '1000px'">
        <report-user-form :reportUser="reportUser" :user="user" @close="reportUser=false"/>
    </u-modal>
</template>


isMobile() {
  if(/Android|webOS|iPhone|iPad|iPod|BlackBerry|IEMobile|Opera Mini/i.test(navigator.userAgent)) {
    return true
  } else {
    return false
  }
},
```

As you can see I'm simply using the `navigator.useragent` to decide the modal size. I suspect `navigator` doesn't exist yet but the page I'm refreshing uses the `navigator`, but when I visit a different page the `navigator` gets populated hence I don't get the error when I do visit the page that uses `navigator` afterwards? In any case how do I fix this problem?

Comment: I guess it is server side rendered!? There is no window object server side. You should expand the if statement accordingly.,

Comment: Yeah I believe it's server side rendered too. What other conditions should I be checking in the if statement?

Comment: I believe this section of the [vue ssr docs](https://ssr.vuejs.org/guide/universal.html#access-to-platform-specific-apis) should help in your case.

Answer (score 2):

Since you have a server-side rendered page, you could move the browser-specific API into a [client-side lifecycle hook](https://ssr.vuejs.org/guide/universal.html#component-lifecycle-hooks), such as [`mounted`](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/api/#mounted), where `window.navigator` would be available.

1. Declare a data prop (named `"mobile"`):

   ```js
   export default {
     data() {
       return {
         mobile: false,
       }
     }
   }
   ```
2. In the component's `mounted` hook, set `mobile` to the result of `isMobile()`:

   ```js
   export default {
     mounted() {
       this.mobile = this.isMobile()
     }
   }
   ```
3. Update the template to use the `mobile` flag instead of the `isMobile()` method call:

   ```html
   <u-modal v-model="reportUser"
       :min-width="mobile ? '150px' : '700px'"
       :max-width="mobile ? '300px' : '1000px'">
   ```